# SQL Date Condition Referring to A Different Table

Tags: sql, date

I have two views that I am trying to build. View # 1 simply returns a set of referral data with the condition that the referral has originated in the past 14 days (and a few other criteria). This has been completed.

The second, View #2, must return all related referrals for customers who have had a referral in the past 14 days (referrals from View #1), but must be limited to no more than 60 days before the date of the referral in view #1, must not include the same referrals from View #1, and cannot produce related referrals AFTER the related referral from View #1

View # 1: TP.INC_REFERRALS_V

So basically I want to put a date condition in the 2nd view for each referral that is based on its referral counterpart in the 1st view.

So far my conditions at the end of the query are:

`...
    WHERE TP.PROSPECT.PROSPECT_ID IN ((SELECT TP.INC_REFERRALS_V.REFERRAL_TABLE_PROS_ID     FROM  TP.INC_REFERRALS_V))`  --this matches an identifier (prospect_id) to the 1st view     (tp.inc_referrals_v to return all related referrals

`AND TP.REFERRAL_V.REFERRAL_ID NOT IN (SELECT TP.INC_REFERRALS_V.REFERRAL_ID FROM TP.INC_REFERRALS_V)`  -- 
this excludes referrals already returned in the first view

`AND...` -- need the logic for the other criteria.

Suggestions?

The query for the 1st view is below. The 3rd view will be the exact same format but with different conditions.. (this is the part I'm having trouble with)

View #1

```
    SELECT TP.REFERRAL_V.REFERRAL_ID,
TP.REFERRAL_V.PROSPECT_ID AS REFERRAL_TABLE_PROS_ID,  
TP.PROSPECT.PROSPECT_ID,    
TP.PROSPECT.SEARCH_NAME AS CUSTOMER_PROSPECT_NAME,  
TP.PROSPECT.CUSTOMER_ID,  
TP.PROSPECT.CUSTOMER_SINCE,  
TP.PROSPECT.IS_BUSINESS,  
TP.PRODUCT_ML_INFO.PRODUCT_CODE,  
TP.PRODUCT_ML_INFO.PRODUCT_ID,  
TP.REGION_ML_INFO.REGION_DESCRIPTION,  
CASE WHEN (TP.REFERRAL_V.PRODUCT_ID) IS NULL THEN
TP.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ML_INFO.PROD_CAT_DESCRIPTION ELSE 
TP.PRODUCT_ML_INFO.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION END AS PROD_CAT_NAME,
TP.REFERRAL_V.PROD_CATEGORY_ID,  
(VXUZ.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || VXUZ.LAST_NAME)    AS CREATED_BY,
(VXU2.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || VXU2.LAST_NAME) AS ASSIGN_TO,
CASE WHEN (TP.REFERRAL_V.REFERRAL_STATUS) = '2'   
THEN TP.REFERRAL_V.CREDIT_LOCATION_NAME ELSE LCX1.LOCATION_NAME END AS   ASSIGN_TO_COST_CENTER,  
     EXU2.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS ASSIGN_TO_EMP_NUM,
    CXZ1.CODE_TEXT AS STAGE,  
  TP.CODE.CODE_TEXT AS STATUS, 
  TP.REFERRAL_EXTENSION_V.EXTENDED_DATETIME2 AS SOLD_DATE,    
TP.REFERRAL_V.CREATED_WHEN AS ORIGINATION_DATE,  
FROM TP.REFERRAL_V  
(joins removed - too many to list)  
WHERE VXU4.USER_ID <> VXU2.USER_ID  
   AND TRUNC(TP.REFERRAL_V.CREATED_WHEN) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 14) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

---

View1  Results

```
Referral_id    Origination_Date   Prospect_ID
        2001              29-NOV-12             A1
        2002              02-DEC-12             A2
        2003              07-DEC-12             A3
```

View2 Results (should be like):

```
Referral_id   Origination_Date   Prospect_ID
        1995              01-NOV-12             A1  
        1993              25-OCT-12             A2  
        1994              20-OCT-12             A2
        1990              17-OCT-12             A2  
        1989              10-NOV-12             A3
```

As you can see in View2 Results, the results should include ALL related referrals for the "prospect_ids" involved in View1, but should not have any dates BEFORE 60 days ago, and should not include the results in view 1 themselves.

Comment: ca you give us an example of what the view1 results look like, any relevant data in tables, and what you expect as output in view2?  The SQL you posted doesn't have a problem.

Comment: The output for view 2 should be exactly the same as view 1, since it is pulling all same fields (just different date). I just want to be able to produce the logic to be able to limit the view2 date based on the corresponding referral_id in view 1

Comment: well, the schema of the output may be the same for both views, but the rows aren't.  to help, we need to understand the data as well as you do, and you haven't posted any.  Can you give us sample rows with dates showing which ones should be excluded from view2 and why?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added more information above. please let me know if there is anything else you need

Comment: For clarification, the referrals in view2 should not be more than 60 days prior to the specific referral_id it is related to from view 1. so if view 1 has two referrals for the same prospect, the related referrals should be no more than 60 days prior to the earliest of the two referrals from view 1

Comment: ok, and TP.REFERRAL_V contains all 8 rows you've listed above?

Comment: Yes, it contains all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this look?

```
SELECT DISTINCT referralID, r.origination_date, r.prospectID, min_dt
FROM referralV r INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT prospectID, min(origination_date) AS min_dt
    FROM referralv
    WHERE origination_date >= dateadd(d,-14,getdate())
    GROUP BY prospectID
) p ON
r.prospectID = p.prospectid
WHERE
  origination_date < dateadd(d,-14,getdate()) AND
  origination_date >= dateadd(d,-60,min_dt)


CREATE TABLE [referralv](
    [referralID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [origination_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [prospectID] [char](2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (2001,'29-NOV-12','A1');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (2002,'02-DEC-12','A2');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (2003,'07-DEC-12','A3');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (1995,'01-NOV-12','A1');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (1993,'25-OCT-12','A2');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (1994,'20-OCT-12','A2');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (1990,'17-OCT-12','A2');
INSERT INTO [referralv]([referralID],[origination_date],[prospectID]) VALUES
           (1989,'10-NOV-12','A3');
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f96fee/1/2)

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer and I get an invalid identifier error for "dateadd," is there a different syntax that can be used for this?

Comment: sry, Oracle's not my back end.  Try this, though: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?188755-Alternative-for-DateAdd-in-oracle

Comment: The solution appears to be working well! Thank you you much for your help, this is great.

Comment: please consider, then, upvoting and/or accepting the answer.  you'll be more likely to get answers in the future.